# What is the minimum of bytes to encode a number?

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to encode a number in range from 0 to 7^20 (integer). I want to use the minimum of bytes to encode a such number. So what is the minimum of bytes to do that? please help me.
Thank you so much

Comment: This is a very simple question that should be easy to answer if you know what a byte is and some basic math. What have you tried to figure it out?

Comment: 20 x log_2 7 = 57 bit = 8 bytes (The = here means approximately, not equal)

Comment: Is this homework? This sounds like homework.

Comment: yes , i also found out 7bytes, can it down more?

Comment: @MichaelP: No, 8 byte, since you need 57 bit to encode it. You can pack it so that you save 7 bit per number, though.

Comment: i want to compress data, i want to encode that number in minimum of bytes

Comment: Data compression works by taking lots and lots of numbers that have some regular pattern to them, and describing the pattern in such a way that you don't have to specify the numbers in full.  You can't "compress" a single piece of data.

Comment: @librik thanks you, but my data is quite special, the max of number is 7^20. so that why i specific that range.

Comment: If your item of data can take any of `79792266297612001` different values, it's going to take at least 57 bits to store it. That's a fact that's about as fundamental as they come.

Comment: Can you represent 0 to 10^3 in two decimal digits? Or can you load 12 bullets into a 8 bullet gun clip?

Answer (score 1):

Rough estimate: 3 bits are enough to encode 0..7, so 3 ⋅ 20 = 60 bits are enough to encode 0..7<sup>20</sup>.
More accurate: ⌈log<sub>2</sub> 7<sup>20</sup>⌉ = 57 bits are enough.

If the numbers to encode are uniformly distributed over this range, you cannot do better. Otherwise, you can do better on average, by giving shorter codes to the more common numbers.

Comment: thanks you, but this result is same to me, i need it down more.

Comment: @Michael You can't go below that. It's really that simple.

Comment: ok thank you, that really the best result, i cannot go below

Answer (score 1):

You need to encode from 0 to 7<sup>20</sup>, which means 7<sup>20</sup> + 1 values in total. Without any information about the input, the best you can do is ⌈log<sub>2</sub>(7<sup>20</sup> + 1)⌉ = 57 bits per number.

You can give 8 byte per number, which it also easy to decode. But there is a wastage of 7 bit per number.

Another way is to store exactly 57 bit per number and pack the numbers tightly together. You can save 7 bytes per 8 number being stored (so 8 numbers will take up 57 bytes instead of 64 bytes). However, it will be slightly trickier to recover the original number.

My lack of knowledge does not allow me to talk about any method that can do better.

Comment: but i need it better...anyway thank you